# Textblock text with multiple font properties

Tags: c#, wpf, docx

I have a textblock with text like this
SOMEBOLDTEXT + SOMEITALICTEXT + SOMEUNDERLINEDTEXT in a single line How can I add this single line to a single wpf Paragraph  with different font styles (SOMEBOLDTEXT-Fontweight = Bold but not italic) , (SOMEITALICTEXT - Fontstyle = italic but not bold) ... 
Please suggest some solution thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use WPF [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run(v=vs.110).aspx) feature. For example:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="Tex1" FontWeight="Light"/>
  <Run Text="Text2"/>
  <Run Text="Text3" FontWeight="Bold"/>
</TextBlock>
```

And if you're using flow document it should look like:

```
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run FontWeight="Light">Light text</Run>
        <Run FontWeight="Bold">Bold Text</Run>
        <Run FontWeight="UltraLight">UltraLight text</Run>
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

Comment: how can I add this to a paragraph in wpf ?? @Ivan Zub